# Pass non-standard headers from nginx to uwsgi

Tags: http, nginx, http-headers, uwsgi

For example:

```
X_USR_12341_CONNECTION: Stale
X_USR_12341_SEED: uW6HncQwe===
X_USR_12341_STATE: Working
```

Number is changing from client to client.  How could I pass those to uwsgi backend from nginx?

Answer (score 3):

By default nginx passes everything to uWSGI. Headers are prefixed with the HTTP_ string: `HTTP_X_USR_12341_CONNECTION`

If you want to pass things generated by nginx you can use the `uwsgi_param` nginx directive:

```
uwsgi_param FOO bar;
```

Comment: "Number" part is changing, that's the problem.  I'm definitely not putting fourteen million uwsgi_param strings into nginx config.